# Haskell how to make a list of results

Tags: haskell

i am trying to solve my homework, but have no Idea how. pls help me

> Write a method which generates the following list from a function f
>   and a starting value x: [x, f ^ 1 (x), f ^ 2 (x), f ^ 3(x)...] f^n(x) 
>   is the n-time application of f to x.

is the type of function right?

```
gen :: (a->a)->a->Int->[a]
gen f x 0 = [x]
```

Comment: The type signature appears to be correct, unless it's expecting only the n-th term to be returned. In that case it should just return an `a`, not a `[a] `. And note for the actual problem itself though, you'll need to ask a specific question regarding it. It's inappropriate to just post your homework and ask for general help. What *specifically* do you need help with?

Comment: Short answer: `gen f x n = take n (iterate f x)` but you are maybe trying to write the function yourself instead of using builtin functions too much.

Comment: `gen f x = x : gen f (f x)`

Answer (score 1):

I think `iterate` would suffice, it has the signature `iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]`:

For example `iterate (*2) 1` gives you an infinite list of powers of 2 `[1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048,4096,8192,16384,32768,65536,131072,262144,524288, ...]`

or you could do something like:

`gen f x =  x : gen f (f x)`

Comment: My guess is they're expected to implement `iterate` themselves. Otherwise they could just do `gen = iterate` (since the homework doesn't actually specify `n` is a parameter).

Answer (score 0):

i tried to use your advices
so i got this

```
gen :: (a->a)->a->Int->[a]
gen f x 0 = [x]
gen f x n = x  : take (n-1) ( gen f (f x) (n-1))
```

Comment: Good! The `take (n-1)` is superfluous though (and highly performance-diminishing, because it's applied over an over, at every single step); the recursive call only yields a list of length `n-1` anyway. _Anyway_ as Viktor Mellgren said it might not be necessary to limit the list length in any way at all – you can just generate an infinite lazy list, like [`iterate`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:iterate) does, and then pick/prine elements as needed.